# How do I find the angles in this translated coordinate system?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a coordinate system that's fixed on the center of the Earth (assume a sphere).

[image]

I know two angles, $\alpha$ and $\delta$, as shown in the figure. These angles will be used to find the position of a point outside the sphere (the satellite).
Now let's say I moved the coordinate system to a point on the sphere, keeping its orientation. We know the angles of the point as well (latitude and longitude).
Here's my question.
Given that I know $\alpha$, $\delta$, latitude, longitude, and magnitude of R, can I find the new angles $\alpha_t$ and $\delta_t$, that point(?) to the same point as $\alpha$ and $\delta$ ?

Edit: If it is not possible to do so, then can I find a transformation matrix for a unit vector in the original coordinates?

Comment: Giving the radius of the Earth $R$ is not enough. You need also the radius for the satellite.

Comment: Almost duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458123/express-spherical-coordinates-with-different-centers-in-terms-of-each-other)